# How to compare integers in 2 stacks in O(n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, time-complexity

I have two Stacks s1 and s2. s1 containing negative integers and s2 containing positive integers. Both Stacks have been sorted already from lowest value(at the bottom) to highest(at the top). x1 and x2 are integers in s1 and s2. I would like to check both Stacks to see whether [x1 + x2 = a given integer i]. What is the best way(or THE way) to do this in O(n)?

Update: x1 and x2 are integers..sorry

**update 2:** the method returns a boolean value and would have these parameters:

```
boolean method(Stack s1, Stack s2, int i)
```

method would return true if any integer x1 in s1 + any integer x2 in s2 = i

Comment: How does one add two stacks of integers together in a fashion that results in one integer?

Comment: Just going through the both stacks and check? But that would be O(n^2) right?

Comment: do you mean if there are x1 in s1 and x2 in s2 such that x1+x2= given integer ?

Comment: clarify your question then, it makes much more since putting it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean any number in s1 + any number in s2 is a given integer i.

If so,

1. Pop off the top of both stacks
2. Add them
3. Do they equal i

   1. Yes --> you are done
4. Is it greater than i?

   1. YES --> then, the negative number can have no counterpart, throw it away, pop off the next negative number from s1, goto 2
   2. NO --> then, the positive number can have no counterpart, throw it away, pop off the next positive number from s2, goto 2

(at any time, if a stack is empty, you are done -- there is no answer)

EDIT:  I think I am wrong on step 4 based on your sort order -- but this basic idea should be close.

Comment: this will not give you the correct answer, you can pop values off the stack with can still be a good combination with an other value.

Comment: @peer, the values in stacks have been sorted. So that's not problem.

Comment: @Nima - try the following stacks: 1 2 3 4 5 10 16 / -14 -13 -12 -9 -5 -4 -3  and i=5   10 + -5 = 5  but you will not get the result from the algorithm adding an extra stack will help to preserve the values from one of the stacks

Comment: The algorithm only works if the stacks are sorted by absolute value.